# onchange does not work

Tags: javascript, html, onchange

I have this [code](http://jsfiddle.net/yNqnr/)

```
<select id="priority" onchange="myfunction(10);">
    <option>0</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
</select>
```

and what i don't understand that it does not trigger the event on the change of the select tag. Why is that?

Comment: do you mind using jQuery?

Comment: I do use jQuery. The 2.0.3 version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've told jsfiddle to put your JavaScript code inside a "load" handler. Thus, your function isn't global and won't be found when the element changes.

Change the pulldown that currently says "onLoad" to either "no wrap (head)" or "no wrap (body)".

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stick to your own code, then you have to change the handler on jsFiddle as mentioned by @Pointy. But if you want it to be done in another way, then try it as below.

**javaScript :**

```
priority.onchange = function myfunction()
{
    alert("On change worked");
}
```

**jQuery :**

```
$("#priority").change({id : 10}, function(event){
    alert(event.data.id);
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/3dxCg/)